# Role based authorization with Azure ADB2C having mobile app(Xamarin Forms IOS app) as a client

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

We have a scenario where in mobile app(Xamarin Forms IOS APP) logs into the Azure ADB2C and generate a JWT token if the user is a valid user(user is configured in Azure AD B2C). We have a requirement where in, we need to generate a token based on the role i.e. based on the role with which user logs in, we want to generate a token and that token we are trying to use it in subsequent Web API calls.

Articles which we found out on this particular scenario was having web application as a client where in some mechanism of secrets were explained. In the mobile app client scenario, its not possible to have a secrets.

Followed the below mentioned article, but couldn't get any concrete information also
https://codemilltech.com/adding-authentication-and-authorization-with-azure-ad-b2c/

Any pointers on this particular scenario would be very much helpful to us.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about an AAD role or an application role?

Comment: Role in the sense I am talking is related to user role something like Administrator/guest/normal user

Comment: What "subsequent Web API" do you want to call? Microsoft Graph API or Azure Rest API or your own API?

Comment: The API will be our own API which is written in ASP.NET core web API.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box support for RBAC / Roles in Azure AD B2C. However there are a lot of samples in the [official GitHub repository](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples). For example the "[Implementing Relying Party Role Based Access Control](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/relying-party-rbac)" by this method you can add the groups to JTW token and also prevent users from sign-in if they aren't members of one of predefined security groups.